# Zoomed skybox in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, plane, skybox

I want to make something like skybox but I want to be able to zoom it. I tried to make a cube with planes and set a camera in the middle. It is not working because I can see the edges. Somebody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Isn't _zooming_ a feature of the _camera_ rather than the skybox?  Otherwise just change your texture co-ordinates of your skybox

Comment: I can zoom gameojects but skybox is always in the same distance.